# Retaining Memory of Initial Properties for Dynamic Buttons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a very simple mix and match system, where the user chooses items from a `select` drop down menu which triggers things. I have buttons that are appended to the document in a rather off the cuff manner, that is to say, whenever the user chooses something from the `select` some text will appear as well as a button to remove that text (and corresponding button).  I'm using D3 to manipulate selections, add classes and append things. I use classes to tell the button which text to remove. All that being said, I believe this still could simply be a native javascript problem I'm running into. The problem is as follows:

After you choose some things from the `select` drop down menu, and then proceed to click the x buttons in the order bottom to top, the behavior is as desired. However, if you click a button at the top or in the middle, the button will not remove the right text. I believe that is because the button is simply removing whatever the latest string value of the dynamic class I'm using. That makes me doubt that the button actually retains the initial properties of its `.on('click', function() {})` (hence the post title).

If that's the case, I'm not really sure how to circumvent such an issue, as the buttons are dynamic in nature.

Very short and simple example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/dff9e4ee397a8772a7f3a6ef369aaba2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to retain memory kind of thing just make sure your element is accessible one such scenario would be to `save the id reference of element as class of another element` like this

```
d3.select('body').append('button')
    .text('X')
    .attr('id','b'+(intCount+1))
    .attr('class',choice+'1') //class is the id of the text element
    .on('click', function(d,i) {
    var t = d3.select(this).attr('id')
    var c = d3.select(this).attr('class')  
      var thisChoice = choice;

      d3.selectAll('.' + t).remove(); //remove this element
      d3.selectAll('.'+ c).remove(); //remove text element
      intCount -= 1;
      count -= .7;
    });
```

working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kn57530n/3/)